# How to subtract neighbouring vectors in a numpy array from each other

Tags: python, numpy

My expected results are as follows:

```
array = [[2,3,4], [1,2,4]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 0]  # [2-1, 3-2, 4-4]
```

I tried doing this by enumerating and getting the indexes to subtract with no luck as:

```
for i, k in enumerate(array):
    for j in k:
        return(j[i+1] - j[i])
```

Which gives me:

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: Are you working with a list of lists, or an actual numpy array? There's ambiguity between your title and the content you've shown

Comment: `-np.diff(array, axis=0)`

Comment: @G.Anderson a numpy array. Assume that `array` is np.asarray(array).

Comment: @PaulPanzer that works!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
result = [(i-j) for (i,j) in zip(*array)]
```

**Output:**

```
print (result)
[1, 1, 0]
```

**Explanation:**

`zip(*array)` is equivalent to the list of tuples `[(2,1), (3,2), (4,4)]`